# Does the Last of Us season pass include a multiplayer key?

Tags: psn, the-last-of-us

A friend of mine has inherited a copy of `The Last of Us` from another friend, but the multiplayer key has already been used. As a birthday present, I'd like to buy them the season pass - but I was wondering if that will include a multiplayer key in itself, or if that has to be purchased separately?

I'm unable to find a definitive answer online so have resorted to asking here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only way to get a multiplayer key is to buy a new copy of the game or purchase an Online Pass from the PSN (or an authorized reseller, like Amazon).

The season pass only gets you the three DLC packs a little cheaper than if you bought them separately.

Comment: Sorry but that's wrong - you can buy a multiplayer key from the PSN store - I did so myself.

Comment: Caleb might be wrong about that, but they're correct in answering the point of your question. The Season Pass does not include multiplayer access.

Comment: @Teifi Sorry I was mistaken.